# how can i return value after loop in C

Tags: c

```
/* check for number of friends each user */
for (i=0; i<num_users; ++i) {
    printf("Number of friends of user %d: %d\n", i, findFriends(matrixF, num_users, i));
}


int findFriends (int **F, int size, int user) {  

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        user=0;
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
            user+=F[i][j];
        return (user);
    }
```

This code doesn't return all the numbers of friends, only the one of first user.

Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return after the loop. If you return inside the loop, the loop doesn't continue, since the function is done.

```
user = 0;
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        user+=F[i][j];
}
return user;
```

I don't understand why `user` is an argument to the function, though. You're just overwriting it with `0`.

Comment: that way i get the sum of array, i need to get sum of each column.

Comment: @G_sev07 perhaps you meant to use `user` as an array index instead of having the `i` loop, and store the sum in a different variable

Comment: yes you're righ. that was the problem! now its wokring

Answer (score 1):

Use return after the loop , using return inside the loop will terminate the loop as well as function , "return"  statement terminates the function